# Sublime Text 2: call make with custom shortcut

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, text-editor

I would like to use two different make commands in Sublime Text 2 using two Keyboard shortcuts.
For one of the commands I use a build system (Make) with the F7 shortcut, which works fine.
For the other one I defined a shortcut in the user-key-bindings which I want to execute "make flash" and display the result:

```
{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "exec", "args": {"lineNumberRegex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)", "command": "make flash"} }
```

The white "console" at the bottom appears as it should but the command doesn't get executed and thus I get no output.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Post the key binding for your `make` build file that you are using with `f7`

Comment: I set the build system to Make and use the default key binding:
`{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },`